# Wikidata SPARQL returns too many results

Tags: sparql, wdqs

This is the query that can be executed in https://query.wikidata.org, I am supposed to get only 17 values, but it returns 289 results (17 * 17 = 289).
I want to get property value with its unit. I am specifying `wdt:P2573` just to demonstrate the issue, in real application that property is a variable `?p`.

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT * WHERE {
  wd:Q2 wdt:P2573 ?o.
  wd:Q2 rdfs:label ?entName.
  ?realAtt wikibase:directClaim wdt:P2573.
  ?realAtt rdfs:label ?attName.
  ?realAtt wikibase:propertyType ?wdDataType.

  OPTIONAL {
    ?realAtt wikibase:statementValue ?psv.
    ?realAtt wikibase:claim ?pp.
    wd:Q2 ?pp ?quantityNode.
    ?quantityNode ?psv ?wdv.
    ?wdv wikibase:quantityUnit ?unit.
    ?wdv wikibase:quantityAmount ?qAmount.
    BIND(?qAmount AS ?val)
  }
  BIND(COALESCE(?val, ?o) AS ?val)


  BIND(COALESCE(?unit, "") AS ?unit)
  FILTER(((LANG(?o)) = "en") || ((LANG(?o)) = "") || (!ISLITERAL(?o)))
  FILTER(((LANG(?attName)) = "en") || ((LANG(?attName)) = ""))
  FILTER(((LANG(?entName)) = "en") || ((LANG(?entName)) = ""))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Simple values* of *truthy statements* are not automagically connected with *value nodes* ([class diagram](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Data_model)).

Your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should look like this:

```sql
SELECT * WHERE {
  wd:Q2 wdt:P2573 ?o.
  OPTIONAL {
    wd:Q2 p:P2573/psv:P2573 ?wdv.
    ?wdv wikibase:quantityUnit ?unit.
    ?wdv wikibase:quantityAmount ?qAmount.
    # FILTER( ?unit != wd:Q199 )
  }
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%2a%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20wd%3AQ2%20wdt%3AP2573%20%3Fo.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20wd%3AQ2%20p%3AP2573%2Fpsv%3AP2573%20%3Fwdv.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fwdv%20wikibase%3AquantityUnit%20%3Funit.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fwdv%20wikibase%3AquantityAmount%20%3FqAmount.%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20FILTER%28%20%3Funit%20%21%3D%20wd%3AQ199%20%29%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

In the query above, the only joining condition of `?o` and `?wdv` is their relatedness to `wd:Q2`.
Hence, you obtain cartesian product of `?o` and `?wdv` bindings (right, 17×17 = 289).

The correct query should look like this:

```sql
SELECT * WHERE {
  wd:Q2 p:P2573/psv:P2573 ?wdv.
  OPTIONAL {
    ?wdv wikibase:quantityUnit ?unit.
    ?wdv wikibase:quantityAmount ?qAmount.
  }
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%2a%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20wd%3AQ2%20p%3AP2573%2Fpsv%3AP2573%20%3Fwdv.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fwdv%20wikibase%3AquantityUnit%20%3Funit.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fwdv%20wikibase%3AquantityAmount%20%3FqAmount.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

**Update**

The above query works for [quantities](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Quantity) only. Obviously, it doesn't work for times or globe coordinates. Moreover, sometimes statements don't have full values at all. For example, statements with string objects have simple values only. One should get simple values from statements and then try to get additional info from full values:

```
SELECT * {
  VALUES (?wd) {(wd:P2067)(wd:P1332)(wd:P1814)}
  ?wd wikibase:claim ?p;
      wikibase:statementProperty ?ps;
      wikibase:statementValue ?psv.
  wd:Q2 ?p ?wds.
  ?wds ?ps ?sv.
  OPTIONAL {
    ?wds ?psv ?wdv
    OPTIONAL {?wdv wikibase:quantityUnit ?unit.
    ?wdv wikibase:quantityAmount ?amount}
  }
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%2a%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fwd%29%20%7B%28wd%3AP2067%29%28wd%3AP1332%29%28wd%3AP1814%29%7D%0A%20%20%3Fwd%20wikibase%3Aclaim%20%3Fp%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20wikibase%3AstatementProperty%20%3Fps%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20wikibase%3AstatementValue%20%3Fpsv.%0A%20%20wd%3AQ2%20%3Fp%20%3Fwds.%0A%20%20%3Fwds%20%3Fps%20%3Fsv.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fwds%20%3Fpsv%20%3Fwdv%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fwdv%20wikibase%3AquantityUnit%20%3Funit.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fwdv%20wikibase%3AquantityAmount%20%3Famount%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Overall, statements characteristics can be quite diverse. It is not very convenient to represent all these data in a table format. That is one of the reasons why RDF exists.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand more, from the diagram, can I confirm if I can always get value directly from Value Node and ignore the Simple Value. Whatever value in Simple Value, it will always exist in Value Node too right ?

Comment: No. For example, strings doesn't have full values: see [this](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Value_representation). I supposed you are interested in quantities only. Otherwise, one should get simple values from *statement* (`wds:...`) and then try to get additional characteristics from the full value (`wdv:...`).

Comment: Like [this](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%2a%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fwd%29%20%7B%28wd%3AP2067%29%28wd%3AP1332%29%28wd%3AP1814%29%7D%0A%20%20%3Fwd%20wikibase%3Aclaim%20%3Fp%3B%0A%20%20%20%20wikibase%3AstatementProperty%20%3Fps%3B%0A%20%20%20%20wikibase%3AstatementValue%20%3Fpsv.%0A%20%20wd%3AQ2%20%3Fp%20%3Fwds.%0A%20%20%3Fwds%20%3Fps%20%3Fsv.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fwds%20%3Fpsv%20%3Fwdv%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fwdv%20wikibase%3AquantityUnit%20%3Funit.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fwdv%20wikibase%3AquantityAmount%20%3Famount%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D).

Comment: Ahh ok, my mistake, I meant to say that whatever value of wdt:... there will always be a value in the wds: or wdv: right ? So that I can just read value from wds/wdv instead and ignore the value of wdt. Noted on the not always exist for wdv:

Comment: Yes, it is always possible to use the `p..:/ps:..` path. In some cases, it is possible to use the `p..:/psv:../wikibase..` path. Please note that there also exist the so-called *normalized values*. They are displayed on web pages and may be different from simple and full values. BTW, this should be hard to represent all these things in a table format. That's  one of the reasons why Linked Data exists...

Comment: Hi, I have another similar problem here, according to the ttl format, I am suppose to get only 1 result, but it returns 8. If you can help too ? Thanks a lot. link on next comment.

Comment: [Here it is](https://query.wikidata.org/#select%20%2a%20WHERE%20%7Bwd%3AQ2%20p%3AP1332%20%3Fwds.%20%0A%20%20%3Fwds%20%3Fps%20%3Fwd%20.%0A%20%20%3FrealAtt%20wikibase%3Aclaim%20p%3AP1332%20%3B%0A%20%20wikibase%3AstatementValue%20%3Fpsv%3B%0A%20%20wikibase%3AstatementProperty%20%3Fps%20.%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fwds%20%3Fpsv%20%3Fwdv%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fwdv%20wikibase%3AgeoLatitude%20%3Flat%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wikibase%3AgeoLongitude%20%3Flng%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wikibase%3AgeoPrecision%20%3Fpre%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Comment: @William, minify to `SELECT ?lat ?lng ?pre WHERE `. `"90.0"^^xsd:double` and `"90"^^xsd:decimal` are distinct values. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/49015788/7879193

Comment: That's helpful, it works now thanks. So I assume this is a bug in blazegraph ?

Comment: @William, this is rather an artefact of miscellaneous imports/exports: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T179228. I don't think that `DISTINCT` should involve type casting etc.